# Angular lazy loading modules with custom components

Tags: angular, angular6, angular-components, angular-module

I'm new in Angular and I use lazy-loaded modules with angular routing but I have problem with components.
I can have components for all modules(i.e. `ToastComponent`) and component for only a specific module(i.e. `SidebarComponent` ) associated to a component showed by routing.
I thought that putting in app.module.ts the global modules and in specific modules the single component is the way but it doesn't work. 
I have this `app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ToastComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    AccordionModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ButtonModule,
    SidebarModule.forRoot(),
    TooltipModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    NgxSpinnerModule,
    ToastModule,
    FormsModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    JwtModule.forRoot({
      config: {     
        tokenGetter: () => {
          return localStorage.getItem(environment.tokenName);
        },
      }
    })
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { 
}
```

`app-routing.ts`:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'login', loadChildren: './login/login.module#LoginModule'},
  { path: '', loadChildren: './home/home.module#HomeModule'}
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

home.module.ts

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [
    CommonModule,
    MenubarModule,
    HomeRoutingModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    HeaderComponent,
    ContentRightComponent,
    SidebarComponent,  
    HomeComponent
  ]
})
export class HomeModule { }
```

home.component.html

```
<app-header (sidebarEvent)="sidebarEvent($event)"></app-header>
<app-sidebar [opened]="opened" (sidebarEventChiusura)="sidebarEventChiusura()" ></app-sidebar>
```

home.component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  private title = 'Configurator';
  private opened: boolean = false;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  sidebarEvent(visible: boolean){
    this.opened = !this.opened;
  } 
  sidebarEventChiusura(opened:boolean){
    this.opened=opened;
  }
}
```

sidebar.component.html:

```
<ng-sidebar-container   style="height: 100vh;">
    <ng-sidebar #sidebar mode="push" dock="true" dockedSize="60px" position="left" [(opened)]="opened" >
        <div id="content-sidebar">
            <p>Sidebar contents</p>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-light float-right" (click)="chiudiSidebar()" *ngIf="!opened" style="width:60px">
            <i class="pi pi-angle-double-right"></i>
        </button>
        <button class="btn btn-light float-right" (click)="chiudiSidebar()" *ngIf="opened" style="width:15vw">
            <i class="pi pi-angle-double-left"></i>
        </button>
    </ng-sidebar>
    <div id="content-right" ng-sidebar-content >
        <app-content-right></app-content-right>
    </div>
</ng-sidebar-container>
```

I receive this error more times:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'opened' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-sidebar'.
1. If 'opened' is an Angular directive, then add 'CommonModule' to the '@NgModule.imports' of this component.
2. To allow any property add 'NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component. ("eight: 100vh;">
    <ng-sidebar #sidebar mode="push" dock="true" dockedSize="60px" position="left" [ERROR ->][(opened)]="opened" >
        <div id="content-sidebar">
            <p>Sidebar contents</p>
"): ng:///HomeModule/SidebarComponent.html@1:83
'ng-sidebar' is not a known element:
1. If 'ng-sidebar' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'ng-sidebar' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. ("<ng-sidebar-container   style="height: 100vh;">
    [ERROR ->]<ng-sidebar #sidebar mode="push" dock="true" dockedSize="60px" position="left" [(opened)]="opened" >
"): ng:///HomeModule/SidebarComponent.html@1:4
'ng-sidebar-container' is not a known element:
```

Do you help me to fix this? Thanks

Comment: For what do you use the ToastComponent? To display some messages?

Comment: yes, message in login page and all other pages

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the home module and the sidebar component, the best practice is to keep your "app.module" as clean as possible.

I would create a new module called "layout" were you will add the components which are used for the layout in all the authorized modules, like home.

```
--layout
 --components
   --layout
      --layout.component.html
   --sidebar
      --sidebar.component.html
   -- etc, the rest of the components that are used globally
 --services
```

The layout will be your main component which will include sidebar and will have a  **router-outlet** element for the lazy loaded children.

```
<div class="container">
     <app-side-bar></app-side-bar>
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
```

Now in your **HomeRoutingModule** file you need to add the routes array like this:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LayoutComponent,
    children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'login', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }
    ]
  }
];
```

For the toast component the best practice is to create a new module called "shared" which will keep all the components, services, guards, interceptors. Basically everything which is not related to a specific module.
--shared
 --components
   --toast
      --toast.component.html
 --services
 --guards
 --interceptors

To use a component from this module in the home module you need to add it to the **export** array in your **shared.module.ts** file:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [ToastComponent],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,

    //3rd party components
  ],
  exports: [
    our own custom components
    ToastComponent,

    //3rd party components

  ]
})
```

Now you need to import the shared module in the home module and you can use all the components that are added to the export array.

I hope it helps. If something is not clear I can update my answer.

**EDIT:**
The exception is thrown because the "opened" is not a property of the ng-sidebar so you can't use it as an input:

```
<ng-sidebar #sidebar mode="push" dock="true" dockedSize="60px" position="left" [(opened)]="opened" >
```

Comment: I don't understand the difference between layout and home

Comment: Layout it's a dummy module where you keep the components related to the layout of the application. It's not lazy loaded.

Comment: Home extends the Layout module.

Comment: ok, but keep the problem about component: Can't bind to 'opened' since it isn't a known property of 'ng-sidebar'.

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to import the SidebarModule from the lazy loaded HomeModule, thereby keeping the Sidebar Component declaration and the import close to one another :-)